# Titanium and FontAwesome

Tags: titanium, font-awesome, custom-font

I have found this example: https://github.com/k0sukey/TiIconicFont

On Android it works great, but I can not see the fonts on the iPhone emulator. Does anyone has an idea where the problem can be? I have downloaded the .ttf from the sources and put them in Ressources/fonts/ .

Also I try to put the .ttf in the Ressources/iphone/fonts, but the same result. There are coming empty squares.

Thanks
Nik

Comment: Try cleaning your project. Also are you using RapidDev? If so, you need to restart it.

Comment: I think that Ressources is a copying error. Can you check?

Comment: On iOS you need to refer to a font by its PostScript name. [How to find it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79875/how-can-i-get-the-postscript-name-of-a-ttf-font-installed-in-os-x)